# Count how many times Contact is Populated in a Lookup?

Tags: formula

I would like to have a custom field on a contact record called "# of submitted Referrals this year" that calculates the # of records created this year with that contact populated in it. The contact is being populated in a custom object called conflict check.

For example, if 100 conflict check records were submitted in 2017 and 25 had Bob Smith populated in this contact lookup, 50 had Kate Johnson populated in this conact lookup, and 25 had Mary Wang populated in this contact lookup.

The contact record for Bob would have 25, Kate would have 50 and Mary would have the number 25 populated in the custom field called "# of submitted Referrals this year".

How can I build this rollup?

Answer (score 2):

This is a perfect use case for **[Declarative Lookup Rollup Summaries](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries)**. It is a free open source library which allows you to create rollup summaries for lookup relationships in a point-and-click manner.

After you install the library, all you have to do is create a `Lookup Rollup Summary` record and populate the required fields. You can even add conditions. In your case it would look something like:

- **Parent Object:** Contact
- **Relationship Field:**  Contact__c
- **Child Object:** Conflict_Check__c
- **Relationship Criteria:** CreatedDate = THIS_YEAR
- **Relationship Criteria Fields:** CreatedDate
- **Field to Aggregate:** Id
- **Aggregate Operation:** Count
- **Aggregate Result Field:**  Submitted_Referrals_This_Year__c

I had to guess a bit on some of the names, but that's the basic idea.